# Threads in C; Tcp Chat Programm

Tags: c, multithreading, chat

I'm studying InfoSec and 4 weeks ago we needed to program a little tool that could communicate between 2 PCs via tcp. I have holidays now and I want to use
the time to build this little thing into a chat program.

I am pretty sure that I need Threads for this since I need to listen for 
incomming messages all the time and the recvfrom blocks me from sending messages 
while it is waiting for a new Message.

So my thoughts where that i need 2 seperate Threads, one that listens and one that sends, so I have this "realtime chat feeling".

I already read these 3 articles [The Geek Stuff Thread Tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/) but it isn't getting me anywhere. I have problems finding good explanations to this matter
and I really want to make it on my own, because I'm pretty excited to actually
produce something usefull for the first time.

Do you guys know any good Links to C-Tutorials for this?
And sorry for my bad english, I am really tired at the moment.

Edit:
I just saw that it's considered off topic to ask for off site resources here.

The specific problem I'm having at the moment is that I'am not sure how to implement a thread that does nothing but call the recvfrom and put the recieved message in std.out and continue to listen. I already have this code:

```
    while(loop){
        /* ~~ RECVFROM ~~ */
        printf(YELLOW"@"COLOR_RESET"Waiting for Client-Message!\n");
        sizer = recvfrom(udpsocket,msg,512,0,(struct sockaddr*) &destaddr,&addrsize);
        if(sizer==-1){
                perror("recvfrom");
                return 0;
        }else{
                printf(GREEN">%s\n"COLOR_RESET,msg);
        }
        /* ~~ ~~~~~~~~ ~~*/
    if((*(msg)=='-')&&(*(msg+1)=='x')){
        loop=0;
    }
    memset(msg,'\0',512);
}
```

And I need some help putting it into a Thread I can lookup everything else, I just need some help getting started there.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I believe you can avoid using threads with appropriate use of select(). If you have kqueue(), even better. Nonetheless, threads are probably the natural mechanism to use.

Comment: look up pthread_create()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a complete manual](http://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) ! If you really need to use thread, I hope this will help as it did for me.